# Use multiple lines with Awk

Tags: csv, awk, gawk

I have a CSV that has underscore delimiters. I have 8 lines that need to be converted to one in this way:

```
101_1_variableName_(value)
101_1_variableName1_(value2)
```

into:

```
101 1 (value) (value2)
```

(in different boxes preferably)

The problem is that I don't know how to use multiple lines in awk to form a single line. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: (input + output)

```
101_1_1_trialOutcome_found_berry            
101_1_1_trialStartTime_2014-08-05 11:26:49.510000           
101_1_1_trialOutcomeTime_2014-08-05 11:27:00.318000         
101_1_1_trialResponseTime_0:00:05.804000            
101_1_1_whichResponse_d         
101_1_1_bearPosition_6          
101_1_1_patch_9         
101_1_1_food_11
```

(last part all one line)

```
101 1 1 found_berry 2014-08-05 11:26:49.510000 2014-08-05 11:27:00.318000 0:00:05.804000 d 6 9 11
```

Comment: a small example would be better. Is that the values are enclosed within `()`? What do you mean by `in different boxes preferably` ?

Comment: The values are not enclose in (). They are, however all delineated by underscores if that helps.

Comment: I mean that it is a CSV file and if I were to say give it to someone else to open in excel that it would put each respective value in different boxes.

Comment: Are `variableName` and `variableName1` really different strings? what matches up those two lines to each other? The first two values?

Comment: variableName and variableName1 are different strings. Each of those strings in the eight lines need to be transferred in the same way as those strings. All I did was show the format.

Comment: instead of format, you could post a sample input and expected output.

Comment: I updated the input + output

Comment: did you want to check for the first column in line 1 and the first column in line 2 are same?

Comment: last part of first line is `berry` and not `found_berry`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash=();

while (<DATA>) {
    if (m/^([0-9_]+)_(?:[^_]+)_(.*?)\s*$/) {
        push @{ $hash{join(' ', split('_', $1) )} }, $2;    
    }
}

print "$_ ". join(' ', @{ $hash{$_} })."\n" for (keys %hash);

__DATA__
101_1_1_trialOutcome_found_berry            
101_1_1_trialStartTime_2014-08-05 11:26:49.510000           
101_1_1_trialOutcomeTime_2014-08-05 11:27:00.318000         
101_1_1_trialResponseTime_0:00:05.804000            
101_1_1_whichResponse_d         
101_1_1_bearPosition_6          
101_1_1_patch_9         
101_1_1_food_11
```

Prints:

```
101 1 1 found_berry 2014-08-05 11:26:49.510000 2014-08-05 11:27:00.318000 0:00:05.804000 d 6 9 11
```

Or, perl one line version:

```
$ perl -lane '
> push @{ $hash{join(" ", split("_", $1) )} }, $2 if (m/^([0-9_]+)_(?:[^_]+)_(.*?)\s*$/);
> END { print "$_ ". join(" ", @{ $hash{$_}})."\n" for (keys %hash); }
> ' file.txt
101 1 1 found_berry 2014-08-05 11:26:49.510000 2014-08-05 11:27:00.318000 0:00:05.804000 d 6 9 11
```